# Как сделать видимое изменение размера width справа налево?

Tags: javascript, css

Как правило `width` трансформируется слева направо. Есть ли варианты сделать наоборот? типа -100%.

Приветствуются любые способы кроме изменения позиции элемента. `CSS` или `JS`, `JQuery` - всё равно.

Comment: поясните для чего это нужно

Comment: смотрите здесь. 
https://codepen.io/ghost6666/pen/OZrZPd
нужно чтобы 3-я и 4-я колонки масштабировались влево а не в право

Comment: Тут - [https://codepen.io/stefcharle/pen/Gydvbx](https://codepen.io/stefcharle/pen/Gydvbx) посмотрите способ реализации

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `float:right`:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orangered;
  float:right;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Вариант с `position:absolute`:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orangered;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле без разницы, т.к. пользователь не заметит как она изменяется. Для достижимого желаемого просто нужно прикрепить предмет через `CSS`-свойство `right` к правой стороне:

```js
document.querySelector('.x').onclick = function(e) {
  this.style.width = '125px';
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 36px;
  border: 2px solid #309;
  background: #94f;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  transition: width 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="x">Предмет</div>
</div>
```

Чтобы посмотреть в действии нажмите на фиолетовый прямоугольник.